# Make Category Image a Link

Tags: magento

I am trying to make all the category images into links. I found SheetGeekExcelGeeks answer from a few years back but I am not sure how to go about filling it out for my category images:

any help is greatly appreciated

[Making Category Image a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749268/making-category-image-a-link) is a link to the orginal question and answer

```
 if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) { 
//Add this, which reads: if the following text exists in the file name of the category image then create html with a link for that specific text
    if(substr($_imgUrl,-20)=="some-systematic-identification-text"){
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><a href="http://www.MY_SITE_URL.com" target="_blank"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></a></p>';
    }
//Add this to check for more text
    else if(substr($_imgUrl,-20)=="some-OTHER-systematic-identification-text"){
         $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><a href="http://www.MY_SITE_URL.com" target="_blank"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></a></p>';
     }
//Otherwise - just add the standard html that was there before we made changes
    else{$_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';}
//Part of if-category image - if statement          
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can creat it through otherway..

Simply write code of html & CSS  and then create static block

and past it in static bloc.

now call that static block from headr file..

Comment: create static Block : CMS>static Block > add static block.          

call that static block through '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('topMenu')->toHtml(); ?>'